# Restricting access to site when using IP address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to restrict access to my ASP.NET MVC site to only my DNS.  When accessing my site via IP address (actual controllers and actions, content, images, scripts, etc.), I want it to block.

Example:

- `https://example.com` - all good - pages load, scripts are downloaded and executed, images display, etc.
- `https://1.2.3.4` - all blocked

Hosting note:
I'm hosted in AWS via Elastic Beanstalk - not sure where AWS uses IP addresses and where it uses DNS in the background.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you use single-instance or load-balanced EB environment?

Comment: Load-balanced EB

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you can take to resolve this.

The first is that you can [use AWS WAF with the ALB that Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-host-attacks/) creates, by doing this you're able to block any interactions before they touch your server. The setup would be quite simple:

- A single rule to Allow access when then host header matches your domain name
- By default block all.

The secondary option would be that this is done on the web server itself, the first vhost should act as a catch all for requests. For this you would simply return a `403`, after this add another vhost to include only your domain which would serve as it previously did.